# Función para validar si un numero es mayor a otro

Tags: python

Tengo una función en python que recibe valores de un sensor y necesito ir validando si el valor nuevo es mayor o menor al anterior recibido, me pierdo al momento de intercambiar variables

'''
#esta es la función que recibe los valores:

```
def validar(valor_nuevo):

  #guardar valor entrante en variable
  ....
  resultado = float(valor_nuevo) - float(valor_viejo)
  if(resultado > 2)
    #hace algo
  if(resultado < 2)
    #hace algo

  #actualizar valor viejo para validar siguiente dato
  valor_viejo = valor_nuevo
  ....
```

'''

Algo así pero no logro actualizar los valores

Comment: y el `valor_viejo` donde esta?

Comment: No lo puse porque no tengo claro como actualizarlo, me parece que al inicio el valor viejo valdría cero ya que no hay dato anterior al primer dato

Comment: si tu función es llamada varias veces, como un tipo de *check data* no sirve de mucho, pero si la función ejecuta algún *loop* tendría más sentido

Comment: Es una función que recibirá valores en tiempo real de un sensor y cada valor debe ser comparado con el anterior para notar un cambio drástico en una gráfica es decir cuando la gráfica se dispara hacia arriba el valor de valor_nuevo - valor_viejo = resultado se mantiene positivo pero cuando empieza a decrecer la gráfica el resultado de la resta de valor_nuevo con valor_viejo es negativo

Answer (score 0):

para ese problema yo haría una clase que se llame "Sensor" la cual contenga todas las funciones y cosas relacionadas con el sensor. de la siguiente manera:

```
class Sensor():
    old_value = 0

    def check(self, value):
        results = float(value) - float(self.old_value)

        if(results > 0):
            print("Do something")
        else:
            print("Do something")

        if(results > self.old_value):
            # si entró aquí significa que el valor nuevo es más alto
            print("We got a higher value")

        self.old_value = value


sensor = Sensor();
sensor.check(2)
sensor.check(4)
```

Lo que estoy haciendo es declarar la clase que te dije, luego asignarle una variable llamada old_value en dónde guardaremos el últimos valor para poder hacer las respectivas comparaciones.

El principio de la función lo dejé igual a cómo tu lo tenías sólo que al final agregué lo que comentabas de poder verificar si el número es mayor al anterior